# Find the network throughput in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, networking, ip, throughput

I'm working on making a kind of system monitor, I'm struggling with getting network throughput, it has to be a module of my system monitor. for the moment I'm able to get the number of packets sent and the numbers that I received, but I'm not sure that it represents the network throughput, here is my code.

```
NetworkThroughput::NetworkThroughput( void ) {
    void *oldp[1024];
    size_t oldlen = sizeof(struct ipstat), newlen = 0;
    void * newp = NULL;
    std::stringstream ss;
    sysctlbyname("net.inet.ip.stats", oldp, &oldlen, newp, newlen);
    struct ipstat * g = (struct ipstat *) oldp;
    ss << "IPS RECEIVED = " << std::to_string(g->ips_total) << std::endl << "IPS GENERATED = "
    << std::to_string(g->ips_localout) << std::endl;
    _network = ss.str();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does `iftop`do it?

Comment: You're right - since packets can vary in size, network throughput isn't best measured in packets.  Personally I'd just read and process the file `/proc/net/dev` which has both tx and rx bytes and packets

Comment: Or - if you know the interface name - then reading  (in the case of wlan0) `/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes` might be even easier

Comment: @UKMonkey Hmm, yes, that makes sense, thanks, I'll try that.